# looping multiple arrays simultaneously with ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

Can I traverse two arrays simultaneously using only one `ng-repeat` in AngularJs? If so, then how?

For example I have two arrays

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

array2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
```

It should be able to produce the same index for both the arrays.

Comment: can you clarify your question

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to acces the second array with the index of the first, try this:

```
$scope.arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
$scope.arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

<div ng-repeat="number in arr1">
    Number from array1 = {{number}}
    Number from array2 = {{arr2[$index]}}
</div>
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dm9zhgx9/

Comment: This works only for this particular question, it doesn't work for arrays with different length.

Answer (score 13):

From my knowledge, Angular does not implement something to iterate over multiple arrays.

One solution would be to concat arrays, and iterate over result.

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3,4,5].concat([6,7,8,9,10])">
    {{item}}
</div>
```

Comment: This won't help if both the arrays' elements have to be accessed in the same iteration. for eg : in the same iteration, to get arr1[0] and arr2[0].

Comment: @SidharthRamesh Then take a look at Rus Paul answer

Comment: Yes his answer works, but it'll work only for the particular example in the question right ? I was looking for a more general approach.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for combination of two arrays use javascript [concat()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) function (AngularJS allows `variable in expression` in ngRepeat directive).

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array1.concat(array2)">{{item}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular

```
$http.get("json/timeline.json")
        .then(function(response) {
            var datalen = response.data.tline.length;           
            for (var i=0; i<datalen; i++){
                vm.eventlist.push(response.data.tline[i]);
                vm.hpos.push({ 'left' : pos * i + 'px'});
            }

        });
```

HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="event in vm.eventlist">
                            <section class="timeline-event past-event" ng-style="{{vm.hpos[$index]}}">
```