# handling two ng-repeat in same table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of images saved in `var images`, and a list of names saved in `var searchName`, now I need to display images along with name, but I could display it after all images displayed only.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row col-sm-12"  >
           <table class="displayImg col-sm-3">

        <tr ng-repeat = "image in images">
        <td><img ng-src="{{image}}" class="imageShow"/> </td>       
        </tr>     
         <tr ng-repeat = "item in searchName">
               <td>{{item[0].profileInfo.firstname}}   </td>
               </tr> 
           </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: If image and name have relation between then merge both array according to your requirement or try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846032/looping-multiple-arrays-simultaneously-with-ng-repeat

Comment: @Nicoleta  - You can first prepare by merging  the data on your controller If there is relation between image and item, You can also try using ng-repeat-start , ng-repeat-end. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Yes I have relationship between images and datas, I will look on to this document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about merge this two into single Array and use ng-repeat.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.images = ['https://angularjs.org/img/AngularJS-large.png', 'http://build.acl.com/assets/tech-logos/angular-03fcc4cfc89d9b310265e7d1e01ee0aef405abf6c632f59342b18848e1c02587.svg'];
  $scope.searchName = ["Angular-Logo", "Angular-SVG-Image"];

  $scope.intrArr = mapImageAndName();

  function mapImageAndName() {
    var mappedArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.images.length; i++) {
      mappedArr.push({
        'image': $scope.images[i],
        'name': $scope.searchName[i]
      });
    }
    return mappedArr;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="row col-sm-12" ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <table class="displayImg col-sm-3">

    <tr ng-repeat="obj in intrArr">
      <td>
        <img ng-src="{{obj.image}}" class="imageShow" />
      </td>
      <td>
        {{obj.name}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested ng-repeat.

```
<div class="row col-sm-12"  >
       <table class="displayImg col-sm-3">

    <tr ng-repeat = "image in images">
    <td><img ng-src="{{image}}" class="imageShow"/> </td>       

     <td ng-repeat = "item in searchName">
          {{item[0].profileInfo.firstname}}   </td>
           </tr> 
       </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into AngularJS ng-repeat document.

There is a term called ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end

[AngularJS ng-repeat Document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat = "image in images">
      <td><img ng-src="{{image}}" class="imageShow"/> </td>
      <td>{{searchName[$index][0].profileInfo.firstname}}   </td>       
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: At looking his code, both array ara mapped to name and image.So,use `$index` from first iteration to take correspodant ele in the sec array