# More than one array in ul li loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-lists

I want to display data in ul / li so I am fetching it through loop in my html like :

I have two array where :

```
  $mainarray = [{"Name":"data1","count":9},{"Name":"data2","count":10},
 {"Name":"data3","count":4},{"Name":"4","count":20}];


 $color = ['red','pink','green','yellow','black'];
 $color = ['red','pink','green','yellow','black'];
```

I am looping through main array like this and its working fine :

```
<ul style="list-style-type:circle; padding: 0px !important; font-size:22px;">
<li ng-repeat="item in mainarray " style="margin-bottom: 10px;"; >
    <span style=" font-size: 16px; ">{{ item.name }}</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

However, I want to add $color with this like :

```
for data1 -> red
data2->pink 
and so on ....
```

I have tried with multiple loop but its not working !

Any clues ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [looping multiple arrays simultaneously with ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846032/looping-multiple-arrays-simultaneously-with-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use `$index`

```
<span style=" font-size: 16px; ">{{ item.name }} -> {{ color[$index] }}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks , but how to place this color in style ? As when i use style = "color={{color[$index]}}, its not working"

Comment: @CodeWithCoffee You can try `ng-style` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364445/apply-css-style-attribute-dynamically-in-angular-js

Comment: This answer from above link https://stackoverflow.com/a/26301609/1984039 does it with plain style.

Comment: Thanks @gurvinder